# Problema com a tabela wp_termmeta

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, wordpress, tabela-html

Está a ocorrer permanentemente o seguinte erro, registado na minha error_log:

Erro na base de dados do WordPress Table

> ```
> 'odiletan_bd.wpTP737termmeta' doesn't exist na query SELECT term_id,
>  meta_key, meta_value FROM wpTP737termmeta WHERE term_id IN
>       (301,308,314,295,311,305,291,298,15,310,303,312,194,316,19,304,7,306,307,292,302,296,313,317,299,160,315,297,203)
> ORDER BY meta_id ASC feita por require('wp-blog-header.php'),
> require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
> include('/themes/colornews-child/single.php'), get_header,
> locate_template, load_template,
>  require_once('/themes/colornews-child/header.php'), wp_nav_menu,
> wp_get_nav_menu_items, get_terms, WP_Term_Query->query,
> WP_Term_Query->get_terms, update_termmeta_cache, update_meta_cache
> ```

Como devo proceder para criar esta tabela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer manualmente pelo prompt de comando, ou baixar o Client Mysql WorkBench no site https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ , ele é todo gráfico, mas você também pode cria-la manualmente usando a tela inicial que ele abre para executar queries. Segue o comando abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `odiletan_bd`.`wpTP737termmeta` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Lembrando que ai ele só esta criando o campo id, você tem que ver quais os outros campos para cria-los, talvez tenha mais campos dos que o que estão nessa query.

Comment: Obrigado. Entretanto eu fui procurar a tabela e ela está presente com os campos: meta_id bigint(20):  term_idÍndice bigint(20); meta_keyÍndice varchar(255) utf8mb4_unicode_ci; meta_value longtext utf8mb4_unicode_ci. O que devo fazer já que ela continua em permanência a enviar aquela msg para a log?

Comment: o tipo dessa tabela é 'myisam' ou 'innodb'?

Comment: O motor de armazenamento é MyISAM.

Comment: Ela pode estar corrompida, utiliza a sintaxe "CHECK TABLE`odiletan_bd`.`wpTP737termmeta`" e se ela estiver utIliza a sintaxe "REPAIR TABLE`odiletan_bd`.`wpTP737termmeta`"

Comment: Como faço isso?  :( desculpe, mas eu não percebo quase nada de BDs

Comment: Botão iniciar do windows, digita prompt, abre ele e digita o seguinte comando: 'mysql -u root -h localhost -p' pressiona enter e digita a senha do banco de dados, digita 'use odiletan_bd' pressiona Enter , digita 'REPAIR TABLE wpTP737termmeta' pressiona Enter. Tudo isso sem as aspas e lembre-se de trocar o root(pelo usuário do banco de dados), localhost(servidor onde o BD esta).

Comment: Afinal a tebela não existe, eu estava a ver noutra BD e não na principal:( Tenho mesmo é que criá-la. :(

Comment: Que bom que encontrou o erro!

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu apoio William Cézar